# How to retrieve only status true or false in below JSON values

Tags: json, mongodb, c#-4.0

```
        Console.WriteLine("mongodb localhost connecting...");
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("mobtions");                  

        var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("AffiliTestStatus");
        var filter = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        filter.Add("offerid", "102030");

        dynamic records = collection.Find(new BsonDocument(filter)).ToList();
```

Here is my JSON response what I had read from above the code

```
{{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e411eca5b7dfc53ac571f71"), "offerid" : "102030", "status" : true }}
```

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```cs
    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("offerid", "102030");
    var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("status").Exclude("_id");
    var options = new FindOptions<BsonDocument> { Projection = projection };
    var records = collection.FindSync(filter, options).ToList();
```